# java swing program not closing after dispose is called on last window

Tags: java, swing, dispose, shutdown

Preface: This is the first real swing program I have done.

I have a swing program, where one JButton is supposed to exit the program. That button triggers this.dispose();. When i click this JButton, it *does* make the window completely go away, but looking at the debugger, the program itself is still running.

My main method only consists of:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
  java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
  {
    public void run()
    {
      new StartupGui().setVisible(true);
    }
  });
}
```

My exit button looks like action button looks like:

```
private void exitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
  this.dispose();
}
```

I have also tried this for the exit button:

```
private void exitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
  java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
  {
    public void run()
    {
      dispose();
    }
  });
}
```

Looking at the debugger after i press the exit button, i see the following (and only the following):

```
Daemon Thread [AWT-XAWT] (running)
Thread [AWT-Shutdown] (running)
Thread [AWT-EventQueue-0] (running)
Thread [DestroyJavaVM] (running)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why the program isn't shutting down after this point? I have done some googling but haven't gotten anywhere thus far. If you need any more information, just let me know

Thanks :)

Comment: what version of the jdk are you running? older versions do not shutdown when all windows are disposed.

Comment: $java -version yields "build 1.6.0_20-b02". Am running this on a 64 bit Arch Linux machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because [dispose()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29) method only releases the resources.

The doc has a

> **Note:** When the last displayable window within the Java virtual machine (VM) is disposed of, the VM ***may*** terminate. See  [AWT Threading Issues](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/AWTThreadIssues.html#Autoshutdown) for more information.

Did you notice the *may*?

The link above gives you detailed information about the *Auto shutdown* feature. You can read more about that, or you can simply solve this by replacing `this.dispose()` with `System.exit(0)`

Answer (score 0):

This Pushing Pixels article: [AWT shutdown and daemon threads](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?p=369) discusses the AWT shutdown behaviour that was changed in 1.4. Still, the article notes that it can be tricky to get a clean shutdown.

Without seeing the rest of the code, I can only offer pointers:

- ensure there are no other hidden frames that have not been disposed
- ensure no messages are being generated on the AWT queue (i.e. set a breakpoint in the EventQueue.)
- otherwise look at the stack frame for these threads and see what they are busy doing