# Why am I get a warning "Dead code"?

Tags: java, warnings

```
    if (myCondition1 && myCondition2 && myCondition3)
    {
    ...
    }
```

I wrote this code and run successfully. but I got warning about part of (...). The warning is "Dead code". It is just interesting to me. Do u have any idea?
thank u

Comment: are you sure you well ever get to the part of code marked "dead"?

Comment: We need some more (real) code to see, why this warning popped up. Usually you have something like `System.exit(0); System.out.println( 'blab' );`, where the second command is never reachable at execution.

Comment: suppose you have myCondition1 = true and myCondition2 = !myCondition1.

Comment: could you post the code before the `if` statment? Are you forcing the value of one of myCondition to false?

Comment: @Sirko In principle you are right but `System.exit()` doesn't affect reachability. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487184/why-is-return-needed-even-after-system-exit0

Comment: post your sample codes where did you face the warning problem, warnings may appear due to listed reasons,mention code does not provide much information

Comment: Probably because it was written in Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Dead code" is code that will never be executed. Most likely one of your conditions is hard-coded to `false` somewhere, making the conditional inside the `if` always false.

Answer (score 3):

Dead code means it is never going to execute. E.g.

```
void someMethod() {
    System.out.println("Some text");
    return;
    System.out.println("Another Some text"); // this is dead code, because this will never be printed
}
```

Same in case of your condition checking e.g.

```
String obj = "";
if(obj == null && obj.equals("")) { // here you get warning for Dead code because obj is not null and first condition is false so obj.equals("") will never evaluate

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code inside the block is never reached. The reason is most likely that one of the conditions is always false.

Answer (score 0):

If one or more of myCondition1, myCondition2 and myCondition3 are always false (like private const bool myCondition1 = false;) then that code inside the if will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

This could occur for a number of reasons. Either the whole of the `if` block is *dead*, caused by something like the following:

```
boolean condition1 = true;
boolean condition 2 = !condition1;

if(condition1 && condition2) {
    //This code is all dead
    Foo f = fooFactory();
    f.barr(new Bazz());
}
```

Or you unconditionally leave the `if` block using something like `return`, `break` or `continue`, as shown below:

```
for(Foo f : foos) {
    if(true) {
        f.barr(new Bazz());
        break;
        //Everything after here is dead
        System.out.println("O noes. I won't get printed :(");
    }
}
```