# How do I terminate my program when more input is entered than required?

Tags: java

I am required to write a program that adds two numbers. It also requires us to display an error message and terminate the program when more than two numbers are entered by the user. I am a beginner and thus I am having trouble in constructing an IF statement that can terminate the program when more than two integers are entered by the user. For instance in the output:

```
Please enter two numbers for addition:
2 2 3
Error! System terminating
```

So how do i make that error message to appear and terminate the program when the user enters more than two integers?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't just post your homework question

Answer (score 0):

use System.exit(1);
this will terminate the program

Comment: Shouldn't it be System.exit(0)?
See link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452930/terminating-java-program](Terminate program)

Comment: we need to pass an int, you can pass any value.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) and read more about `String[] args`.

Then try to answer your question and post your progress here, if you still face some error.