# Program won't end when using clj-statsd

Tags: clojure, statsd

I'm using `clj-statsd` (from [here](https://github.com/pyr/clj-statsd)) to send gauges to a StatsD server. When the program begins, I use `(statsd/setup host port)`, but then the program will not exit when using `lein run`. Even running a simple `(defn -main [] (statsd/setup host port))` will not exit. Any idea on how to shutdown the socket, or whatever is disturbing the program from ending?

Comment: this could help. Since it runs on jvm, all the java techniques are usable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452930/terminating-a-java-program . simple `(System/exit 0)` probably will do

Comment: Yes, I was hoping there's a more subtle way to do this than terminating the process..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since statsd uses agents, you probably just have to call `shutdown-agents`.

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/shutdown-agents