# In java how do I continue the program if the user inputs 'YES' and close it if the user inputs 'NO'?

Tags: java

Hi im trying to make a program which when you run acts like your talking to a robot who will asks some questions about your self but I have included a part where it asks you if you would like to continue but then i get stuck on how to make the program continue running or closing if the user inputs 'NO'. This is all my code so far:

```
/********************
*Husnain Sheraz
*06/08/17
*To test knowledge
*Home
********************/




import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class reviseJava{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws InterruptedException {
        //Introduction just saying my name.
        printWithDelays("Hello my name is HUS9.EXE", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 100);

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);

        //Asking user's name and printing it.

        //start a new line
        System.out.println("");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //A prompt for the user to enter his name.
        printWithDelays("What's your name?", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 100);

        //reads the next letters (string) the user presses before hitting enter.
        String usersName = scan.nextLine();

        //printing out the word hello and what ever the user inputted as his/hers name.
        printWithDelays("Hello " + usersName, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 100);

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);


        printWithDelays(" i'm going to ask you some basic questions about yourself. If you would like to continue please type 'YES' if you would not like to continue please type 'NO'.", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 100);

        printWithDelays("Would you like to continue?", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 100);

        String answer = scan.nextLine();

    }














public static void printWithDelays(String data, TimeUnit unit, long delay)
        throws InterruptedException {
    for (char ch:data.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.print(ch);
        unit.sleep(delay);
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to research the  Java.Util.Scanner class.

Comment: @DevelopingDeveloper Not really, that question asks how to get the input, this one is about how to exit based on the value of the variable since the input is already received.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Terminating a Java Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452930/terminating-a-java-program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
System.exit(0)
```

When it matches to 'No'

Comment: @SchoolBoy thanks to you both I got my code working just how i needed it to. I added the line of code if (answer.equals("NO")) System.exit(0);

Answer (score 0):

you can put `System.exit(0);` inside an if statement to end your program

Answer (score 0):

You should check the value with an `if` statement:

```
if(answer.equals("NO")){
    return;
}
```

This will quit the program if the user types in "NO", otherwise it continues.

Comment: I replied to @Akash comment where i did something similar to this thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

Have your code run inside while loop

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input="";

    While(!(input=scan.nextLine()).equals("NO")){

    // your code goes here
    System.out.println("input not NO");
    }
}
```