# How to stop the run of the program in java?

Tags: java

i want get input user, if it was a bigger than 10 , stop run program

**So far, i have this:**

```
int value=sc.nextInt();
if (value>10){
    **Stop running**
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452930/terminating-a-java-program

Comment: If you are in the `main` method, you can `break;` a loop or `return;` from the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just stop the program by adding the line `System.exit(0);`, like

```
int value=sc.nextInt();
if (value>10){
    System.exit(0);
}
```

This terminates the running JVM and — of course — the program running on it.