# Java game not saving variable on reset

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a textbox where you enter a player name and it changes the label to the name entered.  I want to store it so that when I reset the game (Just make a new board) it still says the player name in the label.

These are the fields related to the name:

```
   private JTextField nameEnter = new JTextField("Enter name here");
   private JButton saveName = new JButton("Play");
   private JLabel namelabel = new JLabel("Player 1");
   private static String playername;
```

The reset method.

```
 public void reset(){

 GameBoard.this.setVisible(false);
 GameBoard.this.dispose();
 new GameBoard();
 score = 0;


}
```

When I call a new GameBoard() the UpdateName() funtion is called:

```
  public void UpdateName() {  

  saveName.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
      playername = nameEnter.getText();
      namelabel.setText(playername);
     }
    });
    }
```

1.) Can anyone tell me how to carry the name over to the next game so it displays in the label?
2.) (a bit cheeky here) If you can spot why the reset method does not dispose of the last GameBoard window even though I asked it to?

That would be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556932/how-to-save-the-state-of-my-minesweeper-game-and-then-load-it/19557052#19557052) for a discssion on different persistance APIs available within the default API...

Comment: *"If you can spot why the reset method does not dispose of the last GameBoard window"* - You do create a brand new one after it, but you could also be using `static` references...

Comment: Thanks, ah yes I am using static instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are calling [dispose()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose()), Change your code like.

```
public void reset(){
 GameBoard.this.setVisible(false);

String tempName = GameBoard.this.nameLabel.getText();

 GameBoard.this.dispose();

 GameBoard gb= new GameBoard("Constructor Without Taking Name");
 gb.nameLabel.setText(tempName);

 score = 0;
}
```

Suggestions: do not do all your things in Constructor define in methods and call it accordingly one by one as required, and on reset your `GameBoard` do not flush your frame or window flush your dependent variables only.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you! I was just trying to get it working but i will try to make it more efficient.

Comment: However, for some reason the window does not dispose still.

Comment: Does your `GameBoard` extends `JFrame`?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to store it using the Java `Preferences` class. This will store it somewhere on disk, meaning that it will also survive between invocations of the program.

You can change the stored value every time someone updates the player name, and then when you start a new game, retrieve the value from the stored preferences.

It means that even if you play a game, and then close the application, and come back the next day and play another game, your name will still persist.

Here's a [nice tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPreferences/article.html) on the topic.

Comment: Ok thank you, ill look at it. I was hoping it wouldn't require changing too much code as i'm fairly novice.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of the game board when you do:

```
new GameBoard();
```

So I think you are losing any data entered on the old game referred to as 'this'.

When you create a new game you run your *UpdateName()* method. In this method you get the name by calling:

```
playername = nameEnter.getText();
```

However as this is a new game, the textfield *nameEnter* will be empty would it not?

As chiastic-security said you might want to save these details between games.
Before you call reset maybe you should call a save method & save the details somewhere. That way when you create a new game you can load in your details.

As to your closing problem, *dispose()* only releases the resource. See top answer [java swing program not closing after dispose is called on last window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114756/java-swing-program-not-closing-after-dispose-is-called-on-last-window)

Maybe look at *Gameboard.this.SetVisible(false)* ?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to get a correct model which handles the data saving and handling. If you do so, you can create a new `GameBoard` and retrieve the data from the model class.